# SufficientlySecure/html-textview library HtmlTextView intercepts parent click events

Tags: android, android-layout

Using [this](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview) library for showing html text I stumble upon a problem that any layout which has HtmlTextView as a child becomes non clickable in places which occupied by HtmlTextView.

Question: how to make HtmlTextView stop to intercept click events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that `setHtml(..)` method calls `setMovementMethod(LocalLinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` inside.
It transforms all HtmlTextViews to clickable links. That's why parent's `OnClickListener` wasn't triggered   when HtmlTextView was clicked.

Source code:

```
  public void setHtml(@NonNull String html, @NonNull Html.ImageGetter imageGetter) {
    final HtmlTagHandler htmlTagHandler = new HtmlTagHandler(getPaint());
    htmlTagHandler.setClickableTableSpan(clickableTableSpan);
    htmlTagHandler.setDrawTableLinkSpan(drawTableLinkSpan);
    htmlTagHandler.setListIndentPx(indent);

    html = htmlTagHandler.overrideTags(html);

    if (removeTrailingWhiteSpace) {
        setText(removeHtmlBottomPadding(Html.fromHtml(html, imageGetter, htmlTagHandler)));
    } else {
        setText(Html.fromHtml(html, imageGetter, htmlTagHandler));
    }

    // make links work
    setMovementMethod(LocalLinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Solution: `htmlTextView.setMovementMethod(null);` after `setHtml(..)`

Or make Utils class with method:

```
 public static void setHtml(HtmlTextView htmlTextView, @Nullable String text) {
    htmlTextView.setHtml(text);
    htmlTextView.setMovementMethod(null);
}
```

[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview/issues/157)